# SQL subquery returning more than 1 Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return all the Cabin names whose number accommodation are greater than the average number of people they can accommodate for their cabin type.

```
SELECT CNAME AS "CABIN NAME", NUMACCOM AS "Can Accomodate"
FROM cabinWH 
WHERE NUMACCOM > (SELECT AVG(NUMACCOM)  FROM cabinWH GROUP BY CTYPE)
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I'd answer to just remove the GROUP BY, but I expect you put it there for a reason. So to really answer well, I need to know what you intended the GROUP BY to accomplish.

Comment: The GROUP BY is there so that it returns the "average number of people that can be accommodate *for their cabin type*" rather than just "average number of people they can accommodate". Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to consider a specific type rather than grouping by type which of course will give you multiple rows, 1 per type:

```
SELECT CNAME AS "CABIN NAME", NUMACCOM AS "Can Accomodate"
FROM cabinWH C1
WHERE NUMACCOM > (SELECT AVG(C2.NUMACCOM) FROM cabinWH C2 where C2.CTYPE = C1.CTYPE)
```

Note: you don't need to group if you want an average over the entire result set.

Comment: Thanks Dale for the swift response. I only have 1 table though, the C2 implies I have two table correct?

Comment: C1 and C2 are alias's to the table which you must do when using the same table twice in a query. (And is good practice in general for readable queries)

Answer (score 0):

You should put a where clause in your subquery to ensure that you get a single result out of it :

```
SELECT outerCabin.CNAME AS "CABIN NAME", outerCabin.NUMACCOM AS "Can Accomodate"
FROM cabinWH outerCabin
WHERE NUMACCOM >
(SELECT AVG(innerCabin.NUMACCOM)  FROM cabinWH innerCabin 
where outerCabin.CTYPE = innerCabin.CTYPE GROUP BY innerCabin.CTYPE)
```

Try this..